# Getting error when deploying functions in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase

Hello I am unable deo deploy a firebase app after upgrading to node 10.

This is the log output.

What is wrong ?

I have upgraded firebase tools as well

```
10 silly lifecycle functions@~deploy: Args: [ '-c', 'firebase deploy --only functions' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ deploy: `firebase deploy --only functions`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.35.3/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm- 
lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.35.3/versions/node/v10.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm- 
lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:947:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:236:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd /Users/Sites/teambox-firebase/functions
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.35.3/versions/node/v10.0.0/bin/node" 
"/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/bin/npm" "run" "deploy"
18 verbose node v10.0.0
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error functions@ deploy: `firebase deploy --only functions`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the functions@ deploy script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output 
above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a somewhat old version of node, or there is some misconfiguration.  It appears you are using nvm, so I would strongly suggest updating node with `nvm install 10` if you wish to stick to node 10.  Be sure to close any open command shells and restart.

Comment: It happens to my from time to time even though I'm using Node 12. Now I upgrade to 14 to make sure all is good, but still getting this error from no apparent reason. Can there be anything else causing this problem?

Comment: I made issue on GH: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3153 Would love to hear your thoughts on this